# JMETER: Which requests to load

Tags: performance, load-testing, capacity-planning, jmeter

The question is about load testing a web application, in order to find out server capacity (I should answer the question: For how many users using my web application, the server can handle the requests without any abnormality).

The web application has many requests like Login, save records, search and .... (so many requests) In order to simulate production environment, which requests should I choose to create script for load test. What is the best strategy to choose requests for load testing in order to be close the main environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimally, you will have statistics about how the site is used. Just use them...

If not: Come up with an educated guess how the site will be used and use this as a baseline. For further tests, change this in some directions (e.g. "Instead of `n %` are search requests, adapt for `n+10 %` search requests).

That really is all that can be said about this.  Of course, these days it's not that terrible anymore if you are off with your estimates anyway, as you can quickly scale up or down your environment when using "cloud" infrastructure.

Comment: Actually, as this web application has security issues, I can't use cloud infrastructure. We should load test on main servers at down time or luckily if administrator provides us backup cluster servers same as the main one. The problem is the question thee manager asked me. He wants to know as these servers have normal behavior with this range of users now, then our production environment is safe for how many user increase? (As our users are increase so much). So I should simulate the user's normal acts and it is so much various and it's the bottleneck now

Comment: Yes, if this app is running in production, use the logs to see what percentage of each request type you get and then scale this up...